# How do I add a "search" button in a text input field?

Tags: html, css, icons

How do I create a similar “search” element to the one in [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20101029141935/https://www.53.com/wps/portal/personal)?

[image]

If we view source, he has one textbox followed by a `<span>` tag.

```
<input type="text" name="q" id="site-search-input" autocomplete="off" value="Search" class="gray" />
<span id="g-search-button"></span>
```

Where do I get a similar "magnifying glass" image?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put the image into the span, for example using `background-image`, then give it a relative position and move it to the left so it overlaps the right end of the search box, for example:

```
#g-search-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  left: -22px;
  top: 3px;

  background-color: black;  /* Replace with your own image */
}
```

[Working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ujate4)

Comment: @casablanca:Do i need to put background-image instead of  background-color

Comment: @cassablanca: Iam not gettting the Image properly

Comment: @Derby: What did you try? Use something like `background-image: url(filename.png)`.

Comment: @Derby: It works for me. Are you sure the image path is correct?

Comment: @Cassablanca:It is eating my textbox border

Comment: @Derby: Then try moving the `span` further to the left, my example was just for `width: 16px`. Make sure your image isn't too big anyway.

Comment: @Cassablanca:it is Just 10*10 still getting the Same way

Comment: <input type ="TextBox"  class="Txt">
<span class="search-button" style="width: 16px"></span></td>

.Txt  
{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 11px;
 border:1px groove #000000;
 vertical-align:middle;
 clear:both;
}

.search-button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
    left: -22px;
    top: 3px;
    background-image:url(glass.jpg);
}

Comment: @cassablanca:Image i have taken from google it is 10pixwidth *10 pi heightx

Comment: @casablanca - Also some "padding-right" is required otherwise the characters will be hidden behind the image.

Answer (score 15):

Your eyes are deceiving you. The button is not within the text box. Using a background image is **NOT** the way to go, as it wont provide the clickable submit button.

What you need to do is add a wrapper div around the input:text and input:submit.

The wrapper will *look* like it's a text box, but will actually contain a transparent text box and a submit button.  You'll need to specifically *remove* the styles for the input:text and input:submit elements.

It's very important that you keep the submit button, otherwise hitting enter while searching will not have a default reaction. Additionally placing the submit button after the text field allows people to actually click on the button.

You can make your own magnifying image, they're pretty easy to make in a 20x20px transparent png.

```css
.search {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 200px;
}

.search input[type="text"] {
  background: none;
  border: 0 none;
  float: left;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 0;
  width: 180px;
}

.search input[type="submit"] {
  background: #CCCCCC url(path/to/image.jpg);
  border: 0 none;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 0;
  text-indent: 100px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form ...>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you view the page in Google Chrome, right-click on the search button and select “Inspect element”, you’ll be able to see the CSS used to achieve this effect.

If you’re not familiar with CSS, I thoroughly recommend [‘CSS: The Definitive Guide’](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926226).

Comment: +1 for the elegant answer. Firebug for Firefox should be mentioned as well.

Answer (score 1):

A site like Iconspedia has a [number of free icons](http://www.iconspedia.com/search/search/) that are similar.

Wherever you get the icon be careful to ensure that you have the rights to use it in your application. Many graphics are protected and some have restrictive licenses.

Comment: We have Font Awesome and IcoMoon nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a background image on the field then there's no way to bind to it to get the click action.  So the solution is to have a separate search field and image, so you can bind click event in jQuery to the image.  Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzm1k4r8/23/

You can adjust `left:` position to be left or right side of the search box.

Answer (score 0):

To help with user feedback why not add the pointer icon to your mouse when you're hovering over the magnifying glass? Just att this to your CSS:

.search:hover   {
    cursor:pointer; 
}

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to plug a new jQuery plugin I wrote because I feel it answers to the OP's request.
It's called jQuery.iconfield: https://github.com/yotamofek/jquery.iconfield.

It lets you easily add an icon to the left side of your text field. For using the icon as a button, you can easily bind to the 'iconfield.click' event, which is triggered when the user clicks the icon. It also takes care of changing the cursor when the mouse is hovering over the icon.

For instance:

```
$('#search-field').iconfield( {
    'image-url':   'imgs/search.png', // url of icon
    'icon-cursor': 'pointer'          // cursor to show when hovering over icon
} );
$('#search-field').on( 'iconfield.click', function( ) {
    $('#search-form').submit()
}
```

I would love to get some feedback on my work.

Comment: i tried using this plugin but icon-cursor isn't working, iconfield.click is not firing, left: false option is not taking effect either!!

Comment: Hey, please contact me through the email listed on my GitHub profile. I will gladly troubleshoot and fix.