# adding search icon to input box

Tags: javascript, search, input, icons

```
<div id="inputs">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
</div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add input">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#add').click(function(){
 $('#inputs').append('<input type="text" value="">');
});
});
</script>
```

Within the code above, i want to add a search icon for every new input generated with a button (id=add ; not shown here for simplicity). This would be a typical input:

```
<label>
<input type="text" class="search" name="word" autofocus="autofocus" />
<span class="search-icon">
    <span class="glass"></span>
    <span class="handle"></span>
</span>
</label>
```

With CSS i could position the search icons in a fixed way.

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's the CSS code that I'd use:

```
#add {
  padding: 17px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: gray;
  background-image: url('http://i47.tinypic.com/r02vbq.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  outline: 0;
}
```

Note: I added a lot of extra codes to make the search box look better, the necessary code to make the search box apear is padding-left, background-image:url, background-repeat and background-position. Replace "http://i47.tinypic.com/r02vbq.png" with whatever search icon you want.

It's also important to know that now in HTML5, most browsers render

```
<input type="search" results>
```

with a search icon. The input type search makes it a search box, with a "x" button to clear, and adding "results" also displays a search box. Of course you could also add an x button with CSS and JavaScript to a regular search box. It's also important to note that input type search allows very little styling. Demo on Safari on a Mac:

[image: Demo]

Tell me if this helps you, and make sure to mark as the answer. :)

Comment: A M A Z I N G explanation, no doubt it will work, but, do you know if i can, let's say, make the search box transparent, or change the color of the search icon?

Comment: Ah well the codes I provided trap the search icon inside the search box, so making the search box transparent makes the icon transparent. You could, of course, use relative positioning, and that would allow the search icon and the search box to be independent. You could edit the search icon to change the color (this can't be done in CSS), or change it's opacity on a photoediting program, or at that matter, from scratch, but I kinda of like my search icon. :) Here's the example of relative positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/525h6/ . You could also accomplish this with marging,but this will sufice

Comment: Regarding the code in my answer, "outline:0", I was clueless at the time and I think you better read http://outlinenone.com/.

Answer (score 3):

Put the image into the span, for example using `background-image`, then give it a relative position and move it to the left so it overlaps the right end of the search box, for example:

```
#g-search-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  left: -22px;
  top: 3px;

  background-color: black;  /* Replace with your own image */
}
```

[Working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ujate4)

Note: This is not my answer, i've found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079774/1551730)

Answer (score 3):

There's a step by step on kirupa.com here:  http://www.kirupa.com/html5/creating_an_awesome_search_box.htm

With relevant bit of CSS for you here:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-position: 270px -10px;
    background-image: url('http://www.kirupa.com/images/search.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```