# Search bar icon styling

Tags: html, css

I have a search text field. How can i place another search icon in search textfield?

Like one in this Image:

[image]

I need this Magnifying Button in my Textfield ( Which will be click-able )

Here is my Search Field: http://jsfiddle.net/ULtH4/

Here is my Code :

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="search_people" placeholder="Search for people..."  class="search_container_textfield" size="30" value="" id="inputString"   />
```

**CSS:**

```
.search_container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border:solid 1px #DFDFDF;
    padding:2px;
}

    .search_container_textfield {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        float: left;
        font-size: 13px;
        height: 23px;
        padding: 6px 4px;
        position: relative;
        width: 496px;s
    }

    .search_container_text {
    color:#006666; font-size:13px; font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top !important;
    }
```

Comment: check the code in js fiddle and replace the image with your   http://jsfiddle.net/ULtH4/6/

Comment: Its on the wrong side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017464/adding-search-icon-to-input-box

look here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/zSsXM/)

```
<div class="search_container">
  <input type="text" name="search_people" placeholder="Search for people..."  class="search_container_textfield" size="30" value="" id="inputString" />
  <a href="search_people.php?id=123555"></a>
</div>


.search_container_textfield {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 23px;
  padding: 6px 4px;
  position: relative;
  width: 496px;
}
.search_container_textfield:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #00aeff;
}
.search_container a {
  background: url(http://www.extendcomm.com/wp-content/themes/extendcomm/images/icons/icon-search.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px 30px; /* background-size added because original icon is 128x128px */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 37px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
  margin: -37px -6px 0 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.search_container a:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8 url(http://www.extendcomm.com/wp-content/themes/extendcomm/images/icons/icon-search.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px 30px; /* background-size added because original icon is 128x128px */    
}
```

Final result

[image]

And if you want to search id's from search filed below is jQuery solution

```
$(function() {
   $('.search_container a').hover(function() {
      var id = $('.search_container_textfield').val();
      $(this).attr('href', 'search_people.php?id='+id);
   });
});
```

Comment: Can i pass a query string ? search_people.php?id=123555

Comment: I dont understand, please explain a little better. You need whole backend script for search function.

Comment: When i click this icon.. It should bring me to this link : search_people.php?id=123555

Comment: Can this <a href> be a button ? I mean <input type="submit"> ?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap a `<span>` around the input and then use `span:after` to content to it, position it absolute and align it to how you want.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9bxE/) All you need to do is change 'Search' for an icon.

Here is another method I done, which supports 'fontawesome-' fonts.

[This link here has an icon (Which is clickable too)](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpv97/)

Comment: How can i place image there?

Comment: Updated post so it now has icons

Comment: This is not clickable

Comment: Can i pass a query string ? search_people.php?id=123555

Comment: Do you mean like a link? @NewCo