# How to put a button inside of a text entry field in a form on a website using javascript, css, html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to write a greasemonkey script that make a button inside of a text entry form on some websites, so that the text entry forms would look something like this:

```
         ____________________ 
Username:|___________|BUTTON|
         ____________________
Password:|___________|BUTTON|
```

Is there any way I can do this with javascript, html, and css? Note that I want my greasemonkey script to work on website's who's layout I do not know, so I can't use the image repositioning trick as in this post: [How do I add a "search" button in a text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079679/how-do-i-create-a-search-button-within-a-textbox)

Comment: This question may be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314407/how-to-add-button-inside-input

Comment: From what I understand you want to find every form field on the page and inject a button right after each text input element in that form?

Comment: @Fuzzley, You are correct. Shaun, the linked questions are answered using the css repositioning trick that I do not want to use.

Comment: Are you okay with using jQuery? You can do it without jQuery, but it is much more verbose. I can try answer it in the format that you prefer.

Comment: Alright, both methods posted. Let me know if there are any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's start with jQuery, since it's more concise.

```
$('form').each(function () {
    $(this).find('input').filter(':text').each(function () {
        $(this).after($('<button>').text('My Button'));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xERT8/2/

**Edited for non-jquery version.**

Okay, here we go!

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    var form = forms[i];
    var inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
    for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
        var input = inputs[j];
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = 'My Button';
        input.parentNode.insertBefore(button, input.nextSibling);        
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/53QQU/6/

Hope that helps.