# Adding a clickable icon/button to an input field using a chrome extension - HTML,CSS, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a script that will allow me to insert a button into the text field of a web page through a chrome extension. What I want to do is something similiar to what the chrome extension Last Pass does i.e. [insert a button into the login fields of username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdyRB.png). I have used this solution that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117716/how-to-put-a-button-inside-of-a-text-entry-field-in-a-form-on-a-website-using-ja) with the following code example:

```
     var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
     for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
       var form = forms[i];
       var inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
       for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
         var input = inputs[j];
         button.className = "inputFieldButton";
         input.parentNode.insertBefore(button, input.nextSibling);        
       }
     }
```

but the code just appends the button to the end of the input field. Here's my CSS code that I've been using for the button:

```
    .inputFieldButton{
      display: inline;
      padding-right: 50px
      background-image: url("/images/buttonInputField.png");
      cursor: pointer;
      position:relative;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-size: 16px 18px;
      background-position: 98% 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpTCE.png) of that code. Is there a solution that lets me insert the button into the field. I'm pretty new to all of this so any help would be very much appreciated.

Also I've changed the classname in the css file now.

Comment: Hi, did you get any further with doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is merely a css issue, and there are many ways to "put the button inside the input field". You'd better learn some css knowledge before that.

One simple approach would be adding `margin-left: -50px;` to your css file, the pixel size is up to you, and don't forget to modify your code to ensure you button is using the right class ( you just use "inputFieldButton" as class name but in css file it is "inputButton")

Comment: Thanks for the reply, margin left did the trick. Definitley need to have a more in-depth look at CSS which I am now off to do. The class name in the css file is now sorted that was my bad. Thanks again.