# HTML/CSS Button when clicked changes into input field and submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would you go about making a clickable button that changes into an `<input>` field with a `<submit>` button on my website?  Once the button is clicked I want it to slide to the right and then the text input form will come in and be right beside it.  I don't know if I should use CSS or JavaScript. Any help?

Comment: Use JavaScript because you'll need onClick functionality.

Comment: you could use CSS and transition , javascript updates CSS on a loop and a timer , **give us a fiddle**

Comment: You will need javascript to achieve that. You should also use jQuery, mostly for the 'slide' effect

Comment: You're not going to have much luck with this question until you provide what you've actually done first and what your current code looks like.  However, CSS sprinkled with JS should give you what you want.

Comment: Side note: I would avoid "what is the best/fastest" type questions in the future. They are almost always opinion-based.

Comment: @tod Please stop adding "Code Sample" to non-code - most would consider this vandalism. If you feel something should be highlighted, you can make it italic, or, in very selective cases, bold.

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks boss for correction...

Comment: We use exactly [this technique in production](https://idorecall.com). Here's [the CodePen](http://codepen.io/dandv/pen/oXpVOj).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tVnD/)

This isnt perfect, merely a starting point, but a basic premise could be:

HTML

```
<form>
    <button>Slide In!</button>
    <div>
        <input type='text' />
        <input type='submit' />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
form {
    position:relative;
}
form div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:all 1s ease-in;
}
form div.active {
    left:0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('form div').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Okay thank you I'm going to see if i could get this to work.

Comment: You're best off using fixed widths/offsets with this kind of effect if implemented in this way

Comment: Alright thanks man it seems to be fine for now I'll let you know if I need anything.

Comment: Have a look here for a few tweaks: http://jsfiddle.net/3tVnD/1/

Comment: There's a delay between clicking "Slide in" and the input text appearing. [brbcoding's example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22941208/1269037) doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 5):

with label , focus and transition CSS can do something really close to the question :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gualw/

```css
form {
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

label {
  /* make it look like a button */
  width: 4em;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0.25em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4285F4;
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0.25em 0.25em 0.25em -50%;
}

input:focus {
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
}

input:focus+label {
  margin-left: -50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="ipt1" />
  <label for="ipt1"> input 1 </label>
  <input id="ipt2" />
  <label for="ipt2"> input 2 </label>
  <input id="ipt3" />
  <label for="ipt3"> input 3 </label>
</form>
```

Comment: yep , it allows to slide form elements one by one , even textarea , check the demo i updated it with file input and textarea :)

Comment: Upvoted for no JavaScript!

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do something simple like this... Animate the width from 0 to some value...

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="input-txt">
<input type="button" id="input-btn" value="Go">
```

**CSS**

```
#input-txt {
    width: 0;
    transition: width 1s ease-in;
}

#input-txt.active {
    width: 250px;
}
```

**Bit o' JS**

```
document.getElementById('input-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('input-txt').classList.add('active');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gU3XR/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help, i figured it out.

Comment: Good deal, just showing that you don't have to use jQuery just to add a class.

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate it, always good to learn new things. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of CSS and Javascript to achieve this

In the design, make the textbox display=none via css

Bind JS click event to the button (JQuery is a better and faster option) and set textbox display=block. To animate, use Jquery animate or any of the animation preset to show the textbox. The look and feel relies on your css styling

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079679/how-do-i-create-a-search-button-within-a-textbox) for more insights

Answer (score -3):

You would use a combination of both. CSS to do your animations and JavaScript to create the functions that trigger these animations. A good place to start would be the [onClick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event.